# Export-import a value produced in one tex file and use it in another tex file efficiently

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files

Based on [here](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/10/04/latex3-tutorial.html), the following should work but does not. Why? All I want to do is to copy one or two values from one `.tex` file to another: copy `12` from `A.tex` to `B.tex`. Is there a simple way to get this done? Thanks

```
% % A.tex =============================

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

% % File write

\xdef\exportedvalue{12}
\exportedvalue % prints 12

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=myfilename.txt
% \immediate\write\file{Column}
\immediate\write\file{\fpeval{\exportedvalue}}
\closeout\file

% \end{document}

% % B.tex =============================

% \documentclass[12pt]{article}

% \usepackage{xfp}

% \begin{document}

% % File read

\newread\file
\openin\file=myfilename.txt
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \read\file to\fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline
    \xdef\importedvalue{\fpeval{\fileline}} % Do something with \fileline % when I commenting out this line (and \importedvalue), it compiles, but does not import the number
\repeat
\closein\file

\importedvalue %does not print 12 that I can reuse elsewhere in the document % when I commenting out this line (and \xdef\importedvalue{\fpeval{\fileline}}), it compiles, but does not import the number

\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you loading fp package?, you seem to be using the l3 floating point via \fpeval

Comment: you should show the error message you get, but `\jobname-myfilename.txt` is not likely to be the same file as `myfilename.txt`

Comment: also you are looping so even if you did read the correct file you would over-write the value with the `\par` at the end don't you just want to `\input` it?

Comment: Thanks, @David Carliste. In short: I tried `input` but did not work. I kept the loop to easily add another row if needed. I will correct the package. When I run `File read` without calling `\importedvalue`, `A.tex` writes. I can open the `myfilename.txt` file and the `12` is there. So, the problem seems to be in `Read file`. When I try to see `\importedvalue`, the `B.tex` does not compile, otherwise it compiles.

Comment: Please let me know if I can add any other detail to clarify further my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can arrange to simply input the file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

% % File write

\xdef\exportedvalue{12}
\exportedvalue % prints 12

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=myfilename.txt
% \immediate\write\file{Column}
\immediate\write\file{\def\noexpand\importedvalue{\fpeval{\exportedvalue}}}
\immediate\closeout\file

% \end{document}

% % B.tex =============================

% \documentclass[12pt]{article}

% \usepackage{xfp}
% \begin{document}

% % File read

\input{myfilename.txt}

\importedvalue

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Well done. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @David Carlisle. Just a follow up: When I tried to use it with another variable, in this case by replacing `\fpeval{\exportedvalue}` with  `\total{citenum}`, it did not compile; but compiles and works with other numerical values. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @Krantz I have no idea how you defined defined `\total` but if you want to use it inline in a `\write` it needs to _expand_ to the value, not require assignments. l3 fp expressions from `\fpeval` are always expandable. If it is a non-expandable calculation do it first and then save the answer in a command that you can expand to the file write

Comment: Thanks, @David Carlisle. `\total` is from `\usepackage{totcount}`. Keeping `\immediate\write\file{\def\noexpand\importedvalue{\fpeval{\exportedvalue}}}`, I tried using: `\newcommand\exportedvalue{\total{citenum}}` and `\xdef\exportedvalue{\total{citenum}}`: neither worked.

Comment: @Krantz looking at the manual `\total` is highly non-expandable, it makes its own messages and other things you can not use in a `\write`  but it looks like `\totvalue` is provided for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Krantz or use that package's own `\usetotcountfile` mechanism for writing to a file which it explicitly says is of use when using values in one document calculated in another. I have never used the package just skimmed the first couple of pages of the manual

Comment: Hi @David Carlisle. `\totvalue` worked. Again: Well done. Thank you very much. I will explore `\usetotcountfile`.